# Importing a bit type from an Excel spreadsheet into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, types, oledb

I have a spreadsheet, and one of the columns is IsActive, and all the values are 1 (number data type in Excel). In SQL Server, the table its being inserted into has a bit data type for IsActive. However, the error that I get when trying to insert the data is

```
The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type bit of the specified target column.
```

Is there a data type in Excel that will be compatible with a bit in SQL Server?

```
 excelConnection.Open();
                    using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection))
                        {
                            //Give your Destination table name 
                            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Medicine";
                            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
                        }
                    }
```

EDIT: Here's the OleDB command

```
 using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select ...[IsActive]... from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection)
```

I obviously don't want the string IsActive to be inserted into a bit column.

Comment: Is it because of the column name, IsActive, is being picked up as a string?

Comment: I would think so, try converting to bit or boolean explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select ...CAST(COALESCE([IsActive], 0) AS BIT)... from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection)
```